# CD/DVD icon on Unity panel/launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

Is it possible to have CD/DVD icon on the launcher by default (regardless of whether CD/DVD is in the tray or not)?

I have friends who would love to switch to Ubuntu, but Ubuntu does not seem to have drivers for special buttons on the laptop, like the one needed to eject the CD/DVD tray. They own one of those mini laptops which have a CD/DVD tray, but no button on the tray to eject it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to eject CD/DVD drives, you can create a launcher to the following command:

```
eject
```

and lock it to Unity launcher. **This works if the tray is empty, too.**

**Creating a launcher**

Create a new text file with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eject
Exec=eject
Icon=cdrom_unmount
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
```

(you can replace cdrom_unmount with media-eject or any icon you want)

and name it Eject.desktop. Right click that file, select "Permissions" and check "Allow executing file as program". Then you can drag it to the Unity Launcher, and get something like this:

[image: Eject icon in Unity Launcher]

Just click on it and the tray will open.

It's not possible to show Unity CD/DVD drive icons if there is no disc in the tray, so this is the best way to get a Unity eject icon.

Comment: The drives for CD/DVD won't display with that option

Comment: @nastys ,  The drives for CD/DVD don't display with that option.

Comment: Post updated...

Comment: @nastys It's not clear to me where you got that option from. Ubuntu 12.10 does not seem to have it. 
After creating the launcher, will the icon remain on the launcher panel even when CD/DVD is ejected?
The point is to open the tray to place the CD/DVD in. Once the tray already has CD/DVD, its easy to eject it from multimedia applications.

Comment: Post updated, just create a new launcher to "eject" and lock to Unity launcher.

Comment: WOW! GREAT! This is very easy! I hope I could vote up 10 times. Thank you so much! It works perfectly!